# How can I find out how many users already voted to re-open my question?

Tags: support

I posted a question roughly a day ago on SO. It was put on hold within several hours because it was indicated as too broad. I adjusted the contents of the question to be more concise, allowing for a specific answer. SO warned me that if it won't be reopened within 5 days, the question will be closed. I'm aready getting a bit nervous since 20% of this time has already passed. How can I see if the moderators / experienced members agree with the modifications I made? And if it's still not okay, how do I get notified about that, too?

My question is at:

[Extremely fast method for modular exponentiation with modulus and exponent of several million digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696007/extremely-fast-method-for-modular-exponentiation-with-modulus-and-exponent-of-se)

Comment: But you edit now asks for a library recommendation -- which is *also* a RTC. Not a field expert so I cannot recommend how to edit your question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Jongware. I just updated the question to recommend a library capable of the requirements I explained. This narrows it down a lot, there are just very few libraries around capable of what I need. I found and tried 2, and have not been able to even find a 3rd library yet to try out.

Comment: @webdevelopersdiary You still should remove/rephrase that part of the question -- library recommendations are *explicitly* off-topic (there's an entire close reason devoted to that type of question), regardless of the number of libraries capable of fulfilling your requirements. There should be a Meta SE question floating around describing how to turn shopping-list questions into "normal" questions, if you want to take a look. Edit: [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185486). Everything up until the last paragraph seems good to me, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there are four reopen votes:

[image]

I was tempted to also vote - your question seemed quite reasonable. But then I struck this sentence:

> what is the fastest software library available to do a modpow operation given a very large base, exponent and modulus?

which makes your question a candidate for closing for a different reason.... we don't encourage people to ask for recommended/favourite/best off site resources. Can you rephrase that at all?

Comment: Thanks! It seems that I can not see that small detail, I feel better knowing it's about to happen :-) I'll rephrase that part, thanks again.